# Element by element concatenation of two string lists

Tags: string-manipulation, concatenation

I have two lists of strings:

```
month = {january, february, march}
year = {2013, 2013, 2013}
```

I want to concatenante these element by element with the final result of the form:

```
{january 2013, february 2013, march 2013}
```

The closest I have come is the following:

```
Map[StringRiffle[#, " "] &, {month, year}]
```

Which results in:

```
{"january february march", "2013 2013 2013"}
```

Which isn't very close...but at least it doesn't result in an error.

I'm sure this is simple, but I have clearly missed something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

```
StringRiffle /@ Transpose @ {month, year}
```

{"january 2013", "february 2013", "march 2013"}

Your "closest" solution would also be fine if you add `Transpose`:

```
Map[StringRiffle[#, " "] &, Transpose @ {month, year}]
```

{"january 2013", "february 2013", "march 2013"}

Answer (score 6):

```
month = {"january", "february", "march"}
year = {"2013", "2014", "2015"}
MapThread[StringRiffle[{#1, #2}] &, {month, year}]
```

or

```
Inner[StringRiffle[{#1, #2}] &, month, year, List]
```

---

*Result:*

> {"january 2013", "february 2014", "march 2015"}

Answer (score 5):

What you posted for your data isn't actually strings, so I'll assume that it was supposed to be like this:

```
month = {"january", "february", "march"};
year = {"2013", "2013", "2013"};
```

`MapThread` is a useful function for performing some sort of joining of lists that have the same structure. In general it looks like this:

```
MapThread[f, {month, year}]
(* {f["january", "2013"], f["february", "2013"], f["march", "2013"]} *)
```

So, you just need to figure out what `f` you want. Maybe something like this:

```
MapThread[#1 <> " " <> #2 &, {month, year}]
(* {"january 2013", "february 2013", "march 2013"} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Grabbing from Syed

```
month = {"january", "february", "march"}
year = {"2013", "2014", "2015"}
```

One suggestion

```
Apply[StringJoin, Transpose /@ Transpose@{month, year}, 1]
```

A second one

```
Function[{x, y}, StringJoin[ToString /@ {x, y}], 
  Listable][month, year]
```

Both return

> `{"january2013", "february2014", "march2015"}`

Not exactly a third one, but fun nonetheless

```
Function[, {##}, Listable][month, year]
```

> `{{"january", "2013"}, {"february", "2014"}, {"march", "2015"}}`

Answer (score 4):

```
month = {"january", "february", "march"}
year = {"2013", "2014", "2015"}
```

```
BlockMap[StringRiffle,Riffle[month,year],2]

(* {"january 2013", "february 2014", "march 2015"} *)
```

```
 MapThread[StringTemplate["`` ``"], {month,year}]

(* {"january 2013", "february 2014", "march 2015"} *)
```

**Just for fun**

```
MapThread[StringTemplate["`2` `1`", 
  CombinerFunction-> Composition[StringJoin,Capitalize]], {year,month}]

(* {"January 2013", "February 2014", "March 2015"} *)
```

```
MapThread[StringTemplate["`2` `1`", CombinerFunction -> 
  Composition[Decapitalize@*ToUpperCase,StringJoin]], {year,month}]

(*{"jANUARY 2013", "fEBRUARY 2014", "mARCH 2015"} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
month = {"january", "february", "march"}; year = {"2013", "2014", "2015"};
```

#### 9. [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) + [`DateString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html)

```
Map[DateString]@Thread[{month, " ", year}]
```

> ```
> {"january 2013", "february 2014", "march 2015"}
> ```

#### 10. [`Thread`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) + [`StringJoin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html)

```
MapApply[StringJoin]@Thread[{month, " ", year}]
```

> ```
> {"january 2013", "february 2014", "march 2015"}
> ```

```
Activate @ Thread[Inactive[StringJoin][month, " ", year]]
```

> ```
> {"january 2013", "february 2014", "march 2015"}
> ```

```
ReleaseHold @ Thread[Hold[StringJoin][month, " ", year]]
```

> ```
> {"january 2013", "february 2014", "march 2015"}
> ```

Comment: Now we should have more than 10!!! Kudos to everyone :-)

Comment: Many to choose from.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

**11. <>**

```
month = {"january", "february", "march"};year = {"2013", "2014", "2015"}

Table[month[[i]]<>" "<>year[[i]],{i,1,Length [month]}]
```

- {january 2013, february 2014, march 2015} *

Or

```
month[[#]]<>" "<>year[[#]]&/@Range[Length[month]]
```

- {january 2013, february 2014, march 2015} *

Or

```
StringRiffle[{mounth[[#]],year[[#]]}&/@Range[Length[month]]
```

- {january 2013, february 2014, march 2015} *

For responding exactly to your question, we must make year to string before:

```
year={2013,2014,2015};year=ToString[year];
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplaceAll`:

```
Transpose[{month, year}] /. x : {_, _} :> Capitalize@StringRiffle[ToString /@ x]

(* {"January 2013", "February 2013", "March 2013"} *)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[Transpose[{month, year}], x_ :> Capitalize@StringRiffle[ToString /@ x]]

(* {"January 2013", "February 2013", "March 2013"} *)
```